# Android - Kotlin - cannot find symbol DataBindingComponent

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm facing this kind of phantom error. I've tried many ways to resolve this problem but nothing works. I don't know what produces this issue. This is my error in Build Log :

```log
e: /Users/galihlarasprakoso/Projects/Android/surat-kaleng/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/galihlprakoso/com/SuratKaleng/databinding/ActivityLoginBinding.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    protected ActivityLoginBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                    ^
    symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
    location: class ActivityLoginBinding
e: /Users/galihlarasprakoso/Projects/Android/surat-kaleng/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/galihlprakoso/com/SuratKaleng/databinding/ActivityLoginBinding.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
    symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
    location: class ActivityLoginBinding
e: /Users/galihlarasprakoso/Projects/Android/surat-kaleng/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/galihlprakoso/com/SuratKaleng/databinding/ActivityLoginBinding.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
    symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
    location: class ActivityLoginBinding
e: /Users/galihlarasprakoso/Projects/Android/surat-kaleng/app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/galihlprakoso/com/SuratKaleng/databinding/ActivityLoginBinding.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
    symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
    location: class ActivityLoginBinding
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for galihlprakoso.com.SuratKaleng.databinding.ActivityLoginBindingImpl
```

This is my project level `build.gradle.kts` file:

```gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    ext.dagger_version = '2.16'
    ext.glide_version = '4.8.0'
    ext.retrofit_version = '2.4.0'
    ext.rxandroid_version = '2.1.0'
    ext.rxjava_version = '2.2.2'
    ext.support_version = '28.0.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app level `build.gradle.kts` file:

```gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "galihlprakoso.com.SuratKaleng"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                details.useVersion "$support_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"

    //Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"

    //Glide
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"

    //RXJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxandroid_version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjava_version"

    //Material Dialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:2.0.0-beta2'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

    //Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'


    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'versionedparcelable'
    }

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I don't know what's wrong, but when I try to access the variable that I've created in xml via `binding.name_of_variable`, it says: `cannot access class check, your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`.

Comment: Have you tried **Rebuilding Project** ?

Comment: sure. I have try that.

Comment: Show your LoginActivity, as it has components in it that are not compiling (both the code and the xml please)

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?

Comment: This looks like you have a syntax error or a definition missing somewhere (possibly your layout files) which causes your Databinding classes to fail compiling. Usually you can find the error buried at the top of the stacktrace. Alternatively you should pinpoint after which change this started happening - after creating a new layout file maybe? Or it could be new dependency injection - then check that file for errors.

Comment: i have try many methods. but then fixed by using the exact gradle version. trying to invalidate cache and restart. clean and rebuild. then suddenly fixed. dont know the exact solution of this problem. thanks for the responses all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Invalidate Caches/Restart.. in Android Studio.

Select and click `Files->Invalidate Caches/Restart..` .

[image]

This will regenerate the required ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate generated classes. To do this in android studio: **Build->Clean Project** after that **Build->Rebuild Project** or just run project. In terminal (on project root) : **./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build**